# Why wouldn't a 130 volt BR 40 bulb work in my recessed light fixture?

Tags: recessed-lighting

Background:

I noticed that light bulbs in our house burn out too frequently. We don't get even 1/4 the life-span that is advertised. This is frustrating.

Some ten years ago when CFL's came, I tried them and was disappointed completely. The cost was much more than the regular ones and the life-span did not change much either.

When I asked a Home Depot associate he said, it is likely that our house has Voltage spikes and that is contributing to the low life of bulbs. Sounds like a reasonable explanation. He suggested I try 130 volt bulbs. I think the bulbs are lasting longer.

Question:

When I plugged in a regular 130 volt bulb into a recessed light socket (this has Br-30 or Br-40 bulbs) I noticed that the bulb won't light. When I used the same bulb in a regular light socket, it will come on.

When I tried 120 volt Br-30 bulb the recessed light socket, it came ON. This suggests the socket is working.

Can someone explain why this could be.

Could someone recommend a 130 volt Br-30 / Br-40 bulb.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if the bulb is not seating properly in the fixture, possible because of its shape. Are your new 130-volt bulbs wider or shallower than the originals? I've had that problem with some CFL bulbs, where they wouldn't screw in far enough to make electrical contact.

If this is the issue, you might be able to see slight scratching on the sides of the new bulbs where they are rubbing against the edge of the fixture.